# Sql server query to select data implementing for-each logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing sql queries to populate data in my report.  I have data in a table like this...

```
    Name           Gender           MainCategory            SubCategory

    Mark             M              Category 1              Sub Category 1
    Peter            M              Category 1              Sub Category 2
    Gemma            F              Category 1              Sub Category 1
    Paul             M              Category 3              Sub Category 2
    Mike             M              Category 3              Sub Category 4
    Elle             F              Category 3              Sub Category 4
...
...So on
```

How can I implement foreach logic.. would like to see results like..

```
   Description                                              Total

   Total Category 1 Employees of Sub Category 1               2
   Total Category 1 Employees of Sub Category 2               1
   Total Category 3 Employees of Sub Category 2               1
   Total Category 3 Employees of Sub Category 4               2
```

Comment: and your attempt is?......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope following query will help you.

```
SELECT 'Total ' + MainCategory + ' Employees of ' + SubCategory As [Description],
       COUNT(*) As Total
FROM MyTable
Group BY MainCategory, SubCategory
```